# Wrong qstat GPU resource count SGE

Tags: gpu, scheduler, hpc, sungridengine

I have a gpu resource called gpus. When I run qstat -F gpus I get weird output of the format "qc:gpus=-1" , thus negative number of available gpus are reported. If i run qstat -g c says I have multiple GPUs available. Multiple jobs fail because of "unavailable gpus". It's like the counting of GPUs starts from 1 instead of 8 on each node, so if I used more than 1 it becomes negative. My queue is :

```
hostlist           node-01 node-02 node-03 node-04 node-05
seq_no                0
load_thresholds       NONE
suspend_thresholds    NONE
nsuspend              1
suspend_interval      00:05:00
priority              0
min_cpu_interval      00:05:00
processors            UNDEFINED
qtype                 BATCH INTERACTIVE
ckpt_list             NONE
pe_list               smp mpich2
rerun                 FALSE
slots                 1,[node-01=8],[node-02=8],[node-03=8],[node-04=8],[node-05=8]
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you set the "gpus" complex in the host configuration. You can see it if you do

```
qconf -se node-01
```

And you can check the definition of the "gpus" complex with

```
qconf -sc
```

For instance, my UGE has this definition for the "ngpus" complex:

```
#name                      shortcut                   type        relop   requestable consumable default  urgency 

ngpus                      gpu                        INT         <=      YES         YES        0        1000
```

And an example node "qconf -se gpu01":
    hostname              gpu01.cm.cluster
    ...
    complex_values        exclusive=true,m_mem_free=65490.000000M, \
                      m_mem_free_n0=32722.546875M,m_mem_free_n1=32768.000000M, \
                      ngpus=2,slots=16,vendor=intel

You can modify the value by "qconf -me node-01". See the man page complex(5) for details.